# How does one solve this integral equation $1+ax=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x-t)dt$

Tags: integral-equations

I've run into having to solve this equation for $f(x)$:

$$1+ax=\int_{-\infty}^xf(x-t)dt$$

Unfortunately, I am not familiar with solving integral equations.  Can anyone help? Is is even soluble?

**Edit**: Fixed a typo in the upper limit in the integral.

Comment: Is there a typo? Since using the substitution $x-t=s$ in the integral we get that $1+ax$ should be constant and $a=0$.

Comment: I re-checked my math that led to this equation, and indeed found a typo.  Will fix shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same exact substitution Davide points out shows that the RHS is the constant $$\displaystyle \int_0^\infty f(s)ds.$$ So nothing really changes here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that rhs of this equation is constant. Indeed,
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} f(x-t)dt=
\{\tau=x-t\}=
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(\tau)d\tau=
\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)dt
$$
Therefore the lhs of this equation must be constant. But this is possible only if $a=0$. For the case when $a=0$, we have $1=\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)dt$, otherwise there is no solution.

Finally if $a=0$ the solution of this equation is any integrable function $f$ such that $\int\limits_{0}^{+\infty}f(t)dt=1$. If $a\neq 0$, solution doesn't exist.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, Bullmoose Corrected everything you pointed out

Comment: Ok, thank you!  I think I made a deeper mistake in the problem that led me to this question.  I'll dig tomorrow.